# Launching Google MapView in incognito mode programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps, mapview

I am building an app showing a MapView in a Fragment.
It's working fine, but – by any means – is there a way to toggle Google Maps' [incognito mode](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/9430563?hl=en_&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) programmatically before the map is shown?
My app doesn't need features like showing the user's current location or record the search history, so sending less user data to Google would be more user-friendly.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I struggled a lot with mapview, can you please share an image to help you?